# How to add argument in rails_admin calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have installed the gem [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to manage datas of my application.

But because of my models I keep having `ArgumentError`. For example I have a `Location` model with an `has_many` relation with the model `TranslateLocation`.

In the `Location` model I have :

```
def name(language)
    translation(language).try :name
end

protected
def translation(language)
    translate_locations.where(language: language).first
end
```

It result on a "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)" for the `name` method.

I define a variable `@language` in my application controller used in my controllers and views.

How can I edit the default behaviour of rails_admin to use this variable when needed ?

If it help you understand the context, [here is a model of the app db](https://github.com/treyssatvincent/hello-pass/blob/master/model.pdf)

Comment: I have added default values to I18n related methods : `name(language = @language)` It seems to make rails_admin usable. But I don't see it as a good solution.

Comment: Hey was browsing my old comments and saw this, did you ever figure it out?

the issue im seeing is youre using the symbol :name which is calling itself, but youre not passing a language in and it then throws that exception.

Answer (score 0):

This could be nothing, and being a new developer myself i could be completely off the bat, but in you **name** method youre using try **:name**, so youre calling the function but not passing a **language** in. but like i said im new to ruby as well and thats my current understanding of symbols. there also isnt much code to go on so my scope is limited.

Comment: It just return the paramater name from translate_locations if there is one. Else it return the whole object.

Comment: Yes but the solution name(language = @language) would be the correct one, in my opinion. Youre calling the name method and that method is expecting you to pass in a parameter, but since your not passing one in it needs a default.

Comment: translation(language).try :name, is calling itself

Comment: did you ever figure it out?